# PHP Regex Help (converting from preg_match_all to preg_replace)

Tags: php, regex

I'm having a bit of difficulties converting some regex from being used in preg_match_all to being used in preg_replace.

Basically, via regex only, I would like to match uppercase characters that are preceded by either a space, beginning of text, or a hypen. This is not a problem, I have the following for this which works well:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<= |\A|-)[A-Z]/',$str,$results);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($results,true) . '</pre>';
```

Now, what I'd like to do, is to use preg_replace to only return the string with the uppercase characters that match my criteria above. If I port the regex straight into preg_replace, then it obviously replaces the characters I want to keep.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Also, I'm fully aware regex isn't the best solution for this in terms of efficiency, but nonetheless I would like to use preg_replace.

Comment: Could you simply pipe the negation of your regex into preg_replace?

Comment: @Ina Do you mean by adding a (! to the regex? If so I tried that, but because of the look behind, it doesn't have the same effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws),
if you want to keep letters that are

- `A-Z`, and
- preceded by `[space]`, `\A`, or `-`

then you'd want to remove characters that are

- *not* `A-Z`, **or**
- *not* preceded by `[space]`, `\A`, or `-`

Perhaps this (replace match with empty string)?

```
/[^A-Z]|(?<! |\A|-)./
```

See [example here](http://regexr.com?30p1r).

Comment: That's perfect, so it's now matching non A-Z, then a negative lookbehind for characters not preceded by those characters.

Thank you very much for your help on this :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be something like this:

```
$sString = preg_replace('@.*?(?<= |\A|-)([A-Z])([a-z]+)@m',"$1", $sString);
```

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for your reply. That code would still just remove the characters that I want to keep

Comment: Can you post a text for testing ?:) it will be easier to help you with some example.

Comment: $str = "This Is A Test String And-Something";

Sure, this is the test string I'm using, and using preg_match_all, it will return TIATSAS, and I would like to use preg_replace to just keep those characters

Comment: But with that, it just returns the entire string unchanged?

Comment: I fixed mine to return what you need, but Wiseguy suggested really great solution :)

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, it's appreciated :)